# HTTP request failed, statusCode: 403, https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap

Tags: android, flutter, dart, google-maps-android-api-2

I have problem when i click on `Select on Map` and select a location and return, there no static map appears and i get this error:

```
 ════════ Exception caught by image resource service
 ════════════════════════════ The following NetworkImageLoadException
 was thrown resolving an image codec: HTTP request failed, statusCode:403,
 https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=&37.41949787164601,-122.06555999815463&zoom=13&size=600x300&maptype=roadmap&markers=color:red%7Clabel:C%7C37.41949787164601,-122.06555999815463&key="My API KEY"
```

Note: I enable both **Maps Static API** and **Maps SDK for Android**

This is `LocationHelper` class

```
class LocationHelper {
  static String generateLocationPreviewImage({
    double latitude,
    double longitude,
  }) {
    return 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=&$latitude,$longitude&zoom=13&size=600x300&maptype=roadmap&markers=color:red%7Clabel:C%7C$latitude,$longitude&key=$GOOGLE_API_KEY';
  }

  static Future<String> getPlaceAddress(double lat, double lng) async {
    final url =
        'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=$lat,$lng&key=$GOOGLE_API_KEY';
    final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
    return json.decode(response.body)['results'][0]['formatted_address'];
  }
}
```

and here where i use it

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:location/location.dart';
import '../screens/map_screen.dart';
import '../helpers/location_helper.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';

class LocationInput extends StatefulWidget {
  final Function onSelectPlace;
  LocationInput(this.onSelectPlace);

  @override
  _LocationInputState createState() => _LocationInputState();
}

class _LocationInputState extends State<LocationInput> {
  String _previewImageUrl;

  void _showPreview(double lat, double lng) {
    final staticMapImageUrl = LocationHelper.generateLocationPreviewImage(
        latitude: lat, longitude: lng);
    setState(() {
      _previewImageUrl = staticMapImageUrl;
    });
  }

  Future<void> _getCurrentLocation() async {
    try {
      final locData = await Location().getLocation();
      _showPreview(locData.latitude, locData.longitude);
      widget.onSelectPlace(locData.latitude, locData.longitude);
    } catch (error) {
      return;
    }
  }

  Future<void> _selectOnMap() async {
    final selectedLocation = await Navigator.of(context).push<LatLng>(
      MaterialPageRoute(
        fullscreenDialog: true,
        builder: (cxt) => MapScreen(
          isSelecting: true,
        ),
      ),
    );
    if (selectedLocation == null) {
      return;
    }
    // selectedLocation has longitude and latitude of the location which the user had selected
    //print(selectedLocation.latitude);
    _showPreview(selectedLocation.latitude, selectedLocation.longitude);
    widget.onSelectPlace(selectedLocation.latitude, selectedLocation.longitude);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Container(
          height: 170,
          width: double.infinity,
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            border: Border.all(
              width: 1,
              color: Colors.grey,
            ),
          ),
          child: _previewImageUrl == null
              ? Text(
                  'No Loaction is Selected',
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                )
              : Image.network(
                  _previewImageUrl,
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  width: double.infinity,
                ),
        ),
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            FlatButton.icon(
              icon: Icon(Icons.location_on),
              label: Text('Current Location'),
              textColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
              onPressed: _getCurrentLocation,
            ),
            FlatButton.icon(
              icon: Icon(Icons.map),
              label: Text('Select on Map'),
              textColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
              onPressed: _selectOnMap,
            ),
          ],
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: 403 error stands for authorization failure, I suspect it has an invalid API_KEY. Have you generated an API key from your console for your application and used it? if you did, can you make sure you've used the right key without any syntax errors?

Comment: Also, if the code was working so far and if it doesn't work now, it would be because you made too many requests to the same server in a short period. If you did so, you'd have to wait for some time for the server to remove you from whitelist

Comment: yes, you're right. i was using incorrect API Key. Thank u

Comment: @SooryaSRajan so i have a question pls, when i mark the APIs i want to use, it give me a API Key but now when i go into `Credentials`, i found that the API Key that i was using wasn't correct. so does the API Key change through time or what?